# Where can I learn Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am an ASP.net Developer. I have 1.5 years of experience.  I want to learn sharepoint server. I have no ideas where to start.

Please tell me where I can start to my carrier as a Sharepoint developer...

Comment: The best place to learn is here :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of resources for Sharepoint all over the web, it is one of the advantages to working with the platform. As rob mentioned start googling away and you will find plenty of things.

If you are looking for more of a structured course (and willing to pay for it) here are two that I used to get started:

[Lynda.com - Sharepoint 2010 Essential Training](http://www.lynda.com/SharePoint-2010-tutorials/essential-training/65720-2.html)

[PluralSight (See the sharepoint section)](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses)

Many areas also have Sharepoint Regional User Groups that can be a great resource as well. Good Luck!!

Answer (score 1):

A Google search for "Getting Started with SharePoint Development" would be a great place to start.

One of the resources you may find is a blog post I wrote for SharePoint 2010 entitled [Getting Started with SharePoint 2010 Development–Links and Resources](http://msmvps.com/blogs/windsor/archive/2011/08/01/getting-started-with-sharepoint-2010-development-links-and-resources.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I learned sharepoint from this wonderfull book called "Inside Windows SharePoint Services 3.0"

It is probably the oldest version to start,  but the first 2 chapters will make you understand how SharePoint and ASP.Net are related and though unrelated...

Start from Inside Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 and then you can jump to the newest version...