# what exactly is sharepoint?how do i start with it and PHP?

Tags: 2007, list, sharepoint-foundation

I have been trying to use Camelot Php Tools for a while but to no avail :(.Please can anyone tell me how do I get start with Camelot and Sharepoint. I think I have done some mistake in installing or have installed wrong file in wrong place or doing something wrong in settings.php or somethink like that,I just can't get started. Can anyone tell me in detail how do I get started with servers and all that. Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: SharePoint and PHP are rarely mentioned in one sentence. These are two very different concepts.

Answer (score 3):

While I can't provide any assistance with the Camelot PHP tools I can say that I would suggest you get framiliar with Sharepoint prior to trying to throw a third party tool in the mix. Sharepoint is a huge animal that is used for different purposes in different companies and can take years to fully grasp.

**What is sharepoint?**

> SharePoint comprises a multipurpose set of Web technologies backed by a common technical infrastructure. By default, SharePoint has a Microsoft Office-like interface, and it is closely integrated with the Office suite. The web tools are designed to be usable by non-technical users. 
>   SharePoint can be used to provide intranet portals, document & file management, collaboration, social networks, extranets, websites, enterprise search, and business intelligence. It also has system integration, process integration, and workflow automation capabilities.

reference: [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint)

[This question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72620/where-can-i-learn-sharepoint/72624#72624) addresses learning sharepoint and some resources, but first and foremost, Google is your friend and the resources are plentiful.

As far as "servers and all that stuff", if you are just getting started you might want to consider [installing a local copy of sharepoint foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28v=office.14%29.aspx) on your machine. This will become a must have if you decide to get into development and so forth. This will require you to have a 64-bit machine however.